# Soapui add new headers

Tags: dynamic, header, soapui, groove

We are using soapui to test API, currently we have some testcases. I have created new test suit, in this test suite we have more than 120test cases, I need to add additional header in that, please suggest code snippet how can add additional header in this?

Comment: hello, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

you really ought to try something then ask for help, it's the best way to learn.

However, this is not very straightforward. The following snippet will help you I guess, but you'll have to adapt it to your needs.

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuiteList.each
{
    suite ->
    name = suite.getName()

    suite.testCaseList.each{
        TC -> 
        // parse each Test Case
        TC.testStepList.each{
            TS ->
            // parse each Test Step
            if (TS.config.type == "restrequest")
            {
                // only on REST request type steps
                // check its headers
                headers = TS.getHttpRequest().getRequestHeaders()
                //log.info "headers = " + headers
                refHeaderName = "Accept" // search Accept header
                found = false
                headers.find(){
                    hd ->
                    //log.info "header name = ${hd.key}, value = ${hd.value}"

                    if(hd.key == refHeaderName)
                    {
                        found = true
                    }
                }

                if (found == false)
                {
                    log.info "testSuite $name - testCase ${TC.getName()} - testStep ${TS.getName()}"
                    // le header n'existe pas, on le cree
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json")
                    //log.info "add a new header : " + headers
                    TS.testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
                }
            }
        } // TS each
    } // TC 
} // TSuite each
```

This is what I've done in my project, I use REST requests ...

good luck

Alexandre